# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException(0x80004005): Unspecified Error

Tags: c#, ms-access, runtimeexception, oledbconnection, oledbexception

Through a series of loops and Database calls (Select statements only) saved as datatables I am generating a .txt file with the values.  It runs fine for a little while (19 rows...19 full loop cycles) then I get a runtime exception being thrown by connection.Open()

I have the entire loop inside a try catch block in order to catch the exception and produce the message then 2 blank lines then the stack trace.
[image]

I have tried to read this and figure out what to do but I am a bit of a Novice when it comes to DB connections.  I have looked elsewhere but do not seem to find a question that quite fits my situation.

FYI: C# 4.0 Windows Form Application, Access DB

I am hoping to find some suggestions on where to begin looking.  I am positive that my connection is closed when this error is thrown due to the validation i implemented as shown here:

```
internal IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = _assemblyProvider.Factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
            _connectionState = connection.State.ToString();
            if (_connectionState == "Open")
                GetConnection();
            else
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            return connection;
        }
        catch (Exception exept)
        {
            throw new Exception(exept.ToString() + "\n\n" + exept.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This method is being called from here:

```
public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText, string tableName, DbParameterCollection paramCollection, CommandType commandType)
    {
        DataTable dtReturn;
        IDbConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = _connectionManager.GetConnection();
            dtReturn = _dbAdapterManager.GetDataTable(commandText, paramCollection, connection, tableName, commandType);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }

        }
        return dtReturn;
    }

public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText, string tableName, CommandType commandType)
    {
        return ExecuteDataTable(commandText, tableName, new DbParameterCollection(), commandType);
    }

public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText)
    {
        return ExecuteDataTable(commandText, string.Empty, CommandType.Text);
    }
```

and

```
 //read from DB using a SQL statement and return a DataTable 
    internal static DataTable readDB(string SQL)
    {
        var dbHelper = new DbHelper();

        using (IDbConnection connection = dbHelper.GetConnObject())
        {
            return dbHelper.ExecuteDataTable(SQL);
        }
    }
```

Here is the loop (its kinda long and could probably be done better but I just want to find why its breaking after its worked several times)

The exception is thrown from the line that Reads:

```
DataTable iRecNum2ClaimRecNumFromClaim = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);
```

inside this:

```
SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Claim WHERE ClaimStatus <> 1";
DataTable allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1 = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);

if (allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows.Count == 0)
    return;
else
{
    string path = txtExtractFileLocation.Text;

    if (txtExtractFileLocation.Text.Substring(txtExtractFileLocation.Text.Length - 2) == "\\\\")
    {
        path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 1);
    }

    if (path.Substring(path.Length - 1) == "\\")
        path += "DI_Extract.txt";
    else
        path += @"\DI_Extract.txt";

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             rNum = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][2].ToString().Trim();//Claim.InsuredRecNum
             SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Insured WHERE RecNum = " + rNum;
             DataTable allInsuredByRecNum = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);

             lossDate = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][11].ToString().Trim();//Claim.LossDate
             lossDate = (Convert.ToDateTime(lossDate)).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
             reportedDate = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][9].ToString().Trim();//Claim.ReportedDate
             reportedDate = (Convert.ToDateTime(reportedDate)).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
             claim = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim();//Claim.ClaimNumber

             if (chkIncludePaymentsForCurrentMonth.Checked == true)
             {
                 direct = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][4].ToString().Trim();//Claim.DirectReserve
                 WP = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][5].ToString().Trim();//Claim.WPReserve
                 ceded = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][6].ToString().Trim();//Claim.CededReserve
             }
             else
             {
                 direct = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][29].ToString().Trim();//Claim.MonthEndDirect
                 WP = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][30].ToString().Trim();//Claim.MonthEndWP
                 ceded = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][31].ToString().Trim();//Claim.MonthEndCeded
             }

             ced = Convert.ToDecimal(ceded);
             wav = Convert.ToDecimal(WP);
             ceded = ced.ToString("#.##");
             WP = wav.ToString("#.##");

             if (ceded == "")
                 ceded = "0";

             if (WP == "")
                 WP = "0";

             if ((allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][10].ToString().Trim() != null) &&
                            (allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][10].ToString().Trim() != ""))//Claim.WaiverDate
             {
                 onWaiver = "YES";
             }
             else
             {
                 onWaiver = "NO";
             }
             reinsPreNotice = "NO";
             reinsCeded = "NO";

             switch (allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][7].ToString().Trim())//Claim.CededPre
             {
                 case "1":
                 {
                     reinsPreNotice = "YES";
                     break;
                 }
                 case "2":
                 {
                     reinsCeded = "YES";
                     break;
                 }
             }//end switch

             state = allRecsFromClaimNotStatus1.Rows[i][8].ToString().Trim();//Claim.LossState


             lName = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim();//Insured.LastName
             fName = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim();//Insured.FirstName
             mi = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][2].ToString().Trim();//Insured.MI
             policy = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][43].ToString().Trim();//Insured.PolicyNumber
             DOB = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][10].ToString().Trim();//Insured.DOB
             DOB = (Convert.ToDateTime(DOB)).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
             age = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][11].ToString().Trim();//Insured.TrueAge
             issueAge = calculateAge(Convert.ToDateTime(allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][10].ToString().Trim()), //Insured.DOB
                                                Convert.ToDateTime(allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][45].ToString().Trim()));//Insured.EffectiveDate

             SQLString = "SELECT InsuredRecNum, RecNum FROM Claim WHERE InsuredRecNum = " + rNum;
             DataTable iRecNum2ClaimRecNumFromClaim = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);
             rNum = iRecNum2ClaimRecNumFromClaim.Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim();

             issueDate = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][45].ToString().Trim();//Insured.EffectiveDate
             issueDate = (Convert.ToDateTime(issueDate)).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
             sex = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][13].ToString().Trim();//Insured.Gender
             planCode = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][44].ToString().Trim();//Insured.PlanMnemonic
             issueAmt = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][49].ToString().Trim();//Insured.BenefitAmount (Monthly Benefit Amount before Offset)
             benefitPeriod = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][50].ToString().Trim();//Insured.BenefitPeriod

             if (allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][54].ToString().Trim().Length == 2)//Insured.EliminationPeriod
                 eliminationPeriod = "0" + allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][54].ToString().Trim();
             else
                 eliminationPeriod = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][54].ToString().Trim();

             premiumAmount = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][48].ToString().Trim();//Insured.AnnualPremium
             occupationClass = allInsuredByRecNum.Rows[0][55].ToString().Trim();//Insured.OccupationClass

             //select only status = EXEC (0)
             SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Offset WHERE ClaimRecNum = " + rNum + " AND Status = 0";
             DataTable allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0 = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);
             offsetAmt = 0;
             dblSTDOffsetAmount = 0;
             dblRecOffsetAmount = 0;
             RECOffsetOcc = "0";
             RECOffsetExecuted = "0";
             int offsetCount = allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0.Rows.Count;
             if (offsetCount != 0)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < offsetCount; j++)
                 {
                     //accumulate standard offset (STD) and Recovery offset (REC)
                     if (allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0.Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim() == "0")//Offset.Type
                     {
                         //Standard Type
                         dblSTDOffsetAmount += Convert.ToDouble(allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0.Rows[j][4].ToString().Trim());//Offset.Amount
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         //Recovery type
                         dblRecOffsetAmount = Convert.ToDouble(allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0.Rows[j][4].ToString().Trim());//Offset.Amount
                         RECOffsetOcc = allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0.Rows[j][5].ToString().Trim();//Offset.Occurance
                         RECOffsetExecuted = allOffsetByClaimRecNumAndStatus0.Rows[j][6].ToString().Trim();//Offset.Executed

                     }//end if
                 }//end for loop
             }//end if

             STDOffsetAmount = dblSTDOffsetAmount.ToString();
             RECOffsetAmount = dblRecOffsetAmount.ToString();
             if (chkIncludePaymentsForCurrentMonth.Checked == true)
                 SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE InsuredRecNum = " + rNum + " AND IssueDate >= #01/01/" + DateTime.Today.Date.Year + "# AND IssueDate <= #" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() + "#";
             else
                 SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE InsuredRecNum = " + rNum + " AND IssueDate >= #01/01/" + endDate.Substring(endDate.Length - 4) + "# AND IssueDate <= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Date.ToShortDateString() + "#";

             DataTable allPaymentByIRecNumAndIssDateInRange = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);

             YTDPmt = 0;
             if (allPaymentByIRecNumAndIssDateInRange.Rows.Count == 0)
                 YTDPmt = 0;
             else
             {
                 int paymentCount = allPaymentByIRecNumAndIssDateInRange.Rows.Count;
                 double issAmt;
                 for (int k = 0; k < paymentCount; k++)
                 {
                     issAmt = Convert.ToDouble(allPaymentByIRecNumAndIssDateInRange.Rows[0][30].ToString().Trim());//Payment.IssueAmount
                     YTDPmt += issAmt;
                 }// end loop
             }//end if

             YTDPmts = YTDPmt.ToString();

             if (chkIncludePaymentsForCurrentMonth.Checked == true)
                 SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE ClaimRecNum = " + rNum;
             else
                 SQLString = "SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE ClaimRecNum = " + rNum + " AND IssueDate <= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Date.ToShortDateString() + "#";

             DataTable allPaymentByRNum = dbConnect.readDB(SQLString);
             totalPmt = 0;

             if (allPaymentByRNum.Rows.Count == 0)
                 totalPmt = 0;
             else
             {
                 double issAmt = Convert.ToDouble(allPaymentByRNum.Rows[0][30].ToString().Trim());
                 for (int m = 0; m < allPaymentByRNum.Rows.Count; m++)
                 {
                     totalPmt += issAmt;
                 }
             }

             allPmts = totalPmt.ToString();

             //set spacing for output
             string block1 = policy + claim + planCode;
             block1 = setSpacing(block1, 28);
             string block2 = setSpacing(benefitPeriod, 3) + eliminationPeriod + occupationClass;
             block2 = setSpacing(block2, 11);
             issueAmt = setSpacing(issueAmt, 8);

             STDOffsetAmount = setSpacing(STDOffsetAmount, 8);

             RECOffsetAmount = setSpacing(RECOffsetAmount, 8);

             RECOffsetOcc = setSpacing(RECOffsetOcc, 3);

             RECOffsetExecuted = setSpacing(RECOffsetExecuted, 3);

             string block3 = lossDate + age;
             block3 = setSpacing(block3, 13);

             issueAge = setSpacing(issueAge, 3);

             string block4 = issueDate + DOB + sex + onWaiver + premiumAmount;
             block4 = setSpacing(block4, 32);

             reinsPreNotice = setSpacing(reinsPreNotice, 3);
             reinsCeded = setSpacing(reinsCeded, 4);

             double ap = Convert.ToDouble(allPmts);
             allPmts = ap.ToString("#.#");
             allPmts = setSpacing(allPmts, 8);
             YTDPmts = setSpacing(YTDPmts, 8);

             lName = setSpacing(lName, 19);
             fName = fName + " " + mi;
             fName = setSpacing(fName, 20);

             string block5 = state + direct;
             block5 = setSpacing(block5, 10);

             ceded = setSpacing(ceded, 8);

             WP = setSpacing(WP, 8);

             reportedDate = setSpacing(reportedDate, 10);

             //save row data for text file
             dataOutput = (block1 + block2 + issueAmt + STDOffsetAmount + RECOffsetAmount + RECOffsetOcc + RECOffsetExecuted +
             block3 + issueAge + block4 + reinsPreNotice + reinsCeded + allPmts + YTDPmts + lName + fName +
             block5 + ceded + WP + reportedDate);

             //Write to the output record DI_Extract.txt
             sw.WriteLine(dataOutput);

             counter++;
             pbrRecordsProcessed.Value = counter;
         }//end for loop

     }//end streamwriter

 }//end if
```

Comment: It sounds like you are opening the `OleDbConnection` inside the loop. Are you remembering to close the connection before the next iteration? Also, do you really need to open a new connection for each iteration, or could you just open the connection before the loop and then close it afterward? (Without seeing the relevant parts of your code all we can do is guess.)

Comment: @Gord My Data Access is set up to open, execute sql command, then close immediately.  This works without issue everywhere else in my program but for some reason after it has executed 19 full loops it stops every time and gives me that exception.  I am unsure why it would work and then seemingly out of nowhere stop working.

Comment: @Gord Edited my Question to include all the relevant code I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking deeper into the code I realized that the connection was trying to open 3 times before it closed.  Not sure why I was not getting exceptions all the time but correcting this issue not only sped up the application tremendously it cleared the exception.